# Send mail and expire account in 24 hours to register

Tags: php, mysql, cron

I want feature like this,

User will be register to site and can access for 24 hours and then I need to expire their account and send mail for that you can't access longer time.

Is it possible with cron or without cron? how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write the portion of your app that would allow users to register. Once they register, track the date they registered in your MySQL DB. Have a cronjob running every hour to check for accounts that have been registered for 24 hours.

Every account that you find in the DB that has been registered for 24 hours should receive the email you mention via the mail() function.

Once you send the email, set a flag on the account so the next time they attempt to login, they get an error message rather than being able to access the account.

Comment: Hello Raphael Caixeta,
Any idea without cronjob ?

Comment: @Neel nope, not without cronjobs.